# Create new processes and expect output

Tags: c, multithreading, parent-child

I am writing a program that will *eventually* be used to have one child process send randomly generated characters through a pipe to another child process to convert to uppercase values and output, but before I get that far, I am trying to create the child processes and make some expected output. I have written the following application:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, stderr, fprintf */
#include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
#include <unistd.h> /* fork */
#include <stdlib.h> /* _exit */
#include <errno.h> /* errno */

int main()
{
    pid_t writer;
    pid_t reader;

    writer = fork();
    if (writer == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (writer == 0)
    {
        printf("Writer process created.\n");
        reader = fork();
        if (reader == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
            exit(1);
        }

        if (reader == 0)
        {
            printf("Reader process created.\n");
            kill(reader);
            printf("Reader was successfully murdered.\n");
        }
        kill(writer);
    }
    wait();
    printf("Writer killed.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I would ideally like the output to come out as the following:

```
Writer process created.
Reader process created.
Reader was successfully murdered.
Writer killed.
```

But as of this point, it outputs:

```
Writer process created.
Reader process created.
Reader was successfully murdered.
Writer killed.
Writer killed.
Writer killed.
```

It is as if it is going through the entire iteration of the code for the parent process, and two child processes from the point that they are created, which also leads me to believe that they are not being killed at the appropriate time that I want them to. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I like your strings. Although, the last line could be more creative: `printf("In Soviet Russia, program terminates you.\n"); return 0;`.

Comment: Are you sure you want: if (reader == 0) { kill(reader); ... }  ( kill(0); ) ?

Comment: @muntoo Haha - I like your suggestion, I think I'll use that xD

Comment: @ebutusov My intention was to simply have the reader (for now) print out that line indicating that it was created, and then kill it. Then I wanted to kill the writer process next, but I don't think it's working as I intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your **full working example** with pipes (they also synchronize processes, so you do not have to kill them). Bear in mind that reader process is reading very **inefficiently** (by one character - I'll leave it as an exercise to you :))

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, stderr, fprintf */
#include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
#include <unistd.h> /* fork */
#include <stdlib.h> /* _exit */
#include <errno.h> /* errno */
#include <string.h> /* strlen */

int main()
{
    pid_t writer;
    pid_t reader;
    char buf;
    int pipefd[2] = {-1,-1};
    const char* pcszTextToChild = "Text sent to child";

    writer = fork();
    if (writer == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (writer == 0)
    {/* writer process */
        printf("Writer process created.\n");
        if(pipe(pipefd) == -1)
        {
           perror("pipe");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        reader = fork();
        if (reader == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
            exit(1);
        }

        if (reader == 0)
        {/* reader process */
            close(pipefd[1]);  /* Close unused write end */
            printf("Reader process created.\n\tReading: ");
            fflush(stdout);
            while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            printf("Exiting reader process.\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {/* writer process */
            close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
            write(pipefd[1], pcszTextToChild, strlen(pcszTextToChild));
            close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
            wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
            printf("Exiting writer process.\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    wait();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Writer process created.
Reader process created.
    Reading: Text sent to child
Exiting reader process.
Exiting writer process.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not kill-ling anything.  There are a lot of compiler errors, that you managed to dodge, so
I added some header files, and left the errors in kill() and wait().  Also consider catching the return codes and paying attention to them.  With correct headers and/or error trapping you would have seen your problems earlier.  Try a compile and see why things were not doing what you wanted.  Fix the errors and things will improve for you.

```
#include <sys/types.h> /* pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, stderr, fprintf */
#include <unistd.h> /* fork */
#include <stdlib.h> /* _exit */
#include <errno.h> /* errno */
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t writer;
    pid_t reader;

    writer = fork();
    if (writer == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (writer == 0)
    {
        printf("Writer process created.\n");
        reader = fork();
        if (reader == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
            exit(1);
        }

        if (reader == 0)
        {
            printf("Reader process created.\n");
            kill(reader);
            printf("Reader was successfully murdered.\n");
        }
        kill(writer);
    }
    wait();
    printf("Writer killed.\n");
    return 0;
}
```