# How to skip empty lines in a file in C?

Tags: c, loops

I expect this code to print every non-empty line and skip the empty ones. but it prints the whole lines for each loop.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char data[1000][256]={"a line\n", "second one \n", "third one\n"};

void show_data(){
        char line[256];
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                strcpy(line, data[i]);
                if(line[0]!='\n'){
                        printf("%s\n", line);
                }
        }

}

int main(){

        show_data();
        return 0;
}
```

it compiles but nothing prints when run.

Comment: Maybe `if (line[0] != '\0') { printf("%s\n", line); }`

Comment: @pmg What's the difference?

Comment: You should create a [mre]. Try to skip the file reading and just hard code an array.

Comment: @klutt Is this okay now?

Comment: Compare `line[0]` and `'\0'` rather than `'\n'`, but with the edit, I see it won't have the effect I was going after.

Comment: Including code that reads files should only be included if absolutely necessary. It makes it A LOT more time consuming for us to test your code. So skip it and instead initialize `data` directly in the code.

Comment: OP: you need `strcpy(data[j], line);`, and remove the inner loop and to **turn on and mind all warnings**.

Comment: or a basic initializer. `char data[1000][256] = { "This is a non-empty line\n", "Another one\n", "\n" , "\n", "Just had two empty lines and here is one more\n", "\n", "This is the last line\n" };`

Comment: @pmg does this function return true of false?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: @user3121023: only if you open the file with binary mode (`fopen("filename", "rb")`)

Comment: @klutt I've tested the new code. it has the same result and easier to debug.

Comment: @user3121023 no I'm not on windows.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi I'm kind of helping you to learn how to debug atm. Just saying. :)

The test case you have provided cannot possibly show the problem you have, since `data` do not contain any empty lines. Also, while debugging you could also add an `else { printf("SKIPPING LINE\n"); }` to see what is happening. You should also add the exact output you're getting (copy paste) and show how you want it to look instead.

Comment: It would also be good to include the includes and a small main function only doing a single call to `show_data`. In other words, I should be able to copy paste your code without any modifications into a compiler, compile it, run it and when I do I should get the same result as you.

Comment: @klutt aha, thanks, I will try make it better. the way I talk is not the way I want, because I'm not fluent in English.sorry!

Comment: @klutt I changed it. hope it help.

Comment: You need to declare `data` and initialize it in a way that makes it show the problem. As I said, we need to be able to copy paste your code and get the same result.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi Focus now. Your question says that you're having problems with empty lines, but your test case does not contain any empty line. So it could not show the problem. Also, be clear about what output you get and expect. Look at this question for inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/q/9593283/6699433

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi Had a quick look at your code, and you need to learn to debug. You have mixed up the arguments for `strcpy`

Comment: @klutt I think there is empty line. the `data` just have 3 line, but the loop go untill `data[5]`

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi Yes, that is correct. You should not loop until more than the number of strings you have declared.

Answer (score 1):

if you change your condition `line[0]!='\n'`for `line[0]!='\0'`you have a good result.

your code correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char data[1000][256]={"a line", "second one", "third one"};

void show_data(){
        char line[256];
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                strcpy(line, data[i]);
                if(line[0]!='\0'){
                        printf("%s\n", line);
                }
        }

}

int main(){

        show_data();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can opti this prog if you check if str i notre NULL before strcpy